# Error while trying to send email using Gmail SMTP

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp, gmail

I developed a desktop software that gives the option of changing the password to the user if he forgets it, and to reset the password an automatic email should be sent to the user email using Gmail SMTP with a verification code. 
this was working fine until a lot of users start using this function (users from different countries), then my Gmail starts blocking the app from sending emails to the users because of the differents IP's that each user has... I start receiving this email from Gmail:

Someone has your password

Hi Youssef,
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account example@gmail.com, using an application such as an email client or mobile device.
Details:
Friday, July 28, 2017 7:37 PM (Egypt Time)
Egypt*
Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices...

---

Is there any solution for this, please?

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uanWZ.png)

NOTE: I'm allowing access to less secure apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd want to setup a webservice, so your app call the webservice, then the webservice use your credential to send the email

Comment: Also, did your desktop app contain the user's hashed passwords & emails, generating the password reset & confirming it all by itself? That way anyone can decompile your apps or just intercept the email to reset the passwords

Comment: Thanks @Martheen for the quick answer, and yes, all the data as emails, passwords and generated code are encrypted ...

Comment: But i really don't know, how can i use a webservice in a desktop app? if u can help me with that !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: Encrypted? But the password for the encryption is contained in your app. The correct solution is to put those data in your webserver. There's plenty tutorial for calling webservice from any .net app (desktop, mobile or web). SO is not the place for that.

Comment: Okay @Martheen, Thanks for your help, yeah I know I should put my data in a server, and i'll do that of course and i'll try to send email using WebService.

Comment: @VDWWD, Sorry that's not my problem :)